# "Page Array" displaying in title bar on Front Page

Tags: php, title, wp-title

The issue is that the text "Page Array" is displaying in the title bar instead of what was previously there, which was just a "|" separator.

I'm trying to puzzle out why this issue appeared...it came up as I was doing some maintenance work, updating some Wordpress REST API calls to the current syntax...but I can't trace this back to anything I changed.

Has anyone experienced this issue, or do you have suggestions about how to go about debugging it, or override it?

This theme was built using the Sage starter theme.

Any advice is much appreciated. This post has some information but I could track down a function that was causing the issue: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/home-page-title-displays-title-tagline-and-the-words-page-array/

Comment: Use this please `$hook_name = 'wp_title';
global $wp_filter;
var_dump( $wp_filter[$hook_name] );` to get a list of functions that are modifying the title, given that you are using `wp_title()` to output the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to set page title in wordpress.

1) In admin area go to settings >> General Settings. Set "Site Title" field and "Tagline" field values.

2) You can set your page title using [wp_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/) function to set the title of your page.

Using this function you can change your page title based on your page.

3) For SEO purpose you can use [All in One SEO plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/) which allows you to set page title and meta data for each and every page.

4) Also, You can use following jQuery code to remove "page array" string from your page title at the time of page load.

```
<script> 
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var title = jQuery(this).attr('title');

    if(title.contains("– Page Array")){
            var title = title.replace("– Page Array", "");
            document.title = title;
        }
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you - reactivating Yoast SEO did the trick. Not sure where the "page array" was coming from.